# How do i access bookmarks with the ngx-extended-pdf-viewer?

Tags: angular

is there a way to retrieve the bookmarks of a pdf using the ngx-extended-pdf-viewer package? Or maybe programmatically add/remove bookmarks of a pdf using a different package?